# Mongodb query using custom string in python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to query mongodb collection like below..

```
>>> db.ds.find({"from":{'$regex':'Pooja'}}).count()
18
```

But when i am appending this same query with custom string it gives me an error..

```
>>> a = 'Pooja'
>>> querystring = ''
>>> querystring = querystring+"'from':{'$regex':"+a+"}"
>>> querystring
"'from':{'$regex':Pooja}"
>>> db.ds.find({querystring}).count()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I really need more than one parameters in querystring explicitly so i am using this way.
Can anybody help me with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some severe errors in your code.

First of all:

```
db.ds.find({querystring}).count()  # SyntaxError here
```

The problem that this line gives `SyntaxError` because `{object}` syntax is a literal for `set` built-in type, which is available since Python 2.7.x version, so, here you're trying to create a set consisting of one string:

```
{object}  # creates set since Python 2.7
{object1: object2}  # creates dict (object1 should be [hashable][1])
```

Let's see an example of creating set in Python 2.7:

```
s = {1, 2, 3}  # Creating set of three unique elements ({} - set literal)
d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}  # Creating dict of number->letters ({:} - dict literal)
```

The second thing is that MongoDB Python driver (I assume that you use Pymongo) doesn't accept strings as queries. It has it's own API and all queries are made via `dict`s representing JSON objects (note, that Mongo stores all objects inside in binary representation of JSON called BSON).

So here, remember first problem, when you're trying to create `set` instead of `dict`).

Conclusion:

1. Use [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)s to create appropriate [Pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) queries.
2. Create dicts properly (not sets).

Comment: I did it with dictionary approach, Thanks for this. But can you elaborate more with "SyntaxError because {object} syntax is a literal for set built-in type"..

Comment: Updated answer, but you better refer to python documentation in sets: http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html